# Multiple Cells need Preceding Zeros - Combining Cell does not

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have an excel sheet with 3 cells that require preceding zeros for indexing purpose in File360 database software.  The final cell combines these 3 cells' information for purposes of naming the pdf file it talks to.  This final cell does not require the preceding zeros.  Is there a way to have excel read these populated cells but drop the zeros in the final cell only?

Comment: If the values with preceding zeros are already populated in the first 3 cells, then you can use VALUE() function with '&' operator to drop preceding zeros and just concatenate the number values into the next cell.

Answer (score 0):

With the three values in **A1**, **B1**, and **C1**, in **D1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),2,1),A1)-1,99) & MID(B1,FIND(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,0,""),2,1),B1)-1,99) & MID(C1,FIND(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C1,0,""),2,1),C1)-1,99)
```

for example:

[image]

The formula strips all leading zeros from each cell and concatenates them.
It will work whether the cells contain just numerals or a text/numeral mixture.
If the characters to the right of the leading zeros are all numerals, then either of these may be used:

```
=VALUE(A1) & VALUE(B1) & VALUE(C1)
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,VALUE(A1:C1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the first 3 columns are a "Number" Number Format, rather than text, then you can format the first 3 cells/columns to have the number of leading zeros that you need, like this:

[image: Add leading zeros to numbers]

Then use a simple formula to join the 3 cells

```
=A1&B1&C1
```

It will keep the formatting if you copy and paste it out, or save as a csv.